# How do I check if a string containing variables is present in a specific file in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, unix, fish

## Background

I have two files:

- `~/.bash.local # $LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE`
- `~/.fish.local # $LOCAL_FISH_CONFIG_FILE`

I am dynamically adding configurations to each file within a bash script. Each file is parsed by either `~/.bash_profile` if it's for `bash` or `~/.config/fish/config.fish` if it's for `fish`. to implement these configurations.

However, I do not want to add the lines that configure a binary to either file every time I run my bash script. I would like it to do the following:

1. Check if the string (e.g. `BASH_CONFIG` or `FISH_CONFIG`) is contained within each specified file
2. If it isn't contained within the file, `printf` it into the designated file.
3. If it is contained within the file, then do not add it again.

My below script's purpose is to install the `npm` package `n` using [n-install](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install) and add the proper configuration to both `bash` and `fish`.

`execute` is a function that I defined to run the task in the background and display a message on the screen with a spinner.

### Current Bash Script Snippet

```
add_n_configs() {

    # bash

    declare -r BASH_CONFIGS="
# n - Node version management.
export N_PREFIX=\"\$HOME/n\";
[[ :\$PATH: == *\":\$N_PREFIX/bin:\"* ]] || PATH+=\":\$N_PREFIX/bin\"
"

    execute \
        "printf '%s\n' '$BASH_CONFIGS' >> $LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE \
        && . $LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE" \
        "n (update $LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE)"

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # fish

    declare -r FISH_CONFIGS="
# n - Node version management.
set -xU N_PREFIX \"\$HOME/n\"
set -U fish_user_paths \"\$N_PREFIX/bin\" \$fish_user_paths
"

    execute \
        "printf '%s\n' '$FISH_CONFIGS' >> $LOCAL_FISH_CONFIG_FILE" \
        "n (update $LOCAL_FISH_CONFIG_FILE)"

}
```

Comment: You just need *something* like `if ! grep -q N_PREFIX "$file"; then add it; fi`

Comment: @glennjackman is there a way to do the same thing except with `BASH_CONFIGS` or `FISH_CONFIGS`?

Comment: Yes of course. I was trying to give you a hint, not the whole solution. I thought it would be obvious what you would replace `$file` with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research it seems that this task can be accomplished using `grep` as so:

```
if ! grep -q "$BASH_CONFIGS" "$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE"; then
        execute \
            "printf '%s\n' '$BASH_CONFIGS' >> $LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE \
            && . $LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE" \
            "n (update $LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE)"
fi

if ! grep -q "$FISH_CONFIGS" "$LOCAL_FISH_CONFIG_FILE"; then
        execute \
            "printf '%s\n' '$FISH_CONFIGS' >> $LOCAL_FISH_CONFIG_FILE" \
            "n (update $LOCAL_FISH_CONFIG_FILE)"
fi
```

`grep` is a command-line utility that can search and filter text using a common regular expression syntax.

To search for an exact string: `grep search_string path/to/file`

To search for an exact string in quiet mode: `grep -q search_string path/to/file`

- `grep -q` will only search a file until a match has been found.